# How to define complex Maven properties in the comand line

Tags: maven, maven-cobertura-plugin

I'm using the Maven [cobertura plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/cobertura-mojo.html) to retrieve my unit test code covering and I'm using it through the command line:

```
mvn cobertura:cobertura
```

What I would like to do is configure the exclusions from command line. As you can see from the official documentation, we can configure an
 [instrumentation user property](http://www.mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/instrument-mojo.html#instrumentation).

This Instrumentation Configuration object has the below structure:

```
<instrumentation>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>com/example/dullcode/**/*.class</exclude>
  </excludes>
</instrumentation>
```

Is there any way to configure a complex object like the above using only the command line in the form of

```
-Dcobertura.instrumentation.excludes.<something>=com/example/dullcode/**/*.class
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't define a complex parameter on the command line. But you can implement a trick to make this work: define a Maven property that you override on the command-line.

You can configure the plugin with:

```
<instrumentation>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>${cobertura.instrumentation.exclude}</exclude>
  </excludes>
</instrumentation>
```

then, on the command-line, having

```
-Dcobertura.instrumentation.exclude=com/example/dullcode/**/*.class
```

will correctly exclude those classes. And if you don't specify the system property, nothing will be excluded.

Comment: As an addition, if you need multiple excludes, you could define multiple <exclude> tags in the POM and use property names .exclude1, .exclude2 etc. Not very elegant, but does the trick.

Comment: @Tunaki, thank you. Ok I got, but what if my project is a multi module project? I should configure the plugin only in one place, say the parent pom.xml, and exclude all test classes on all modules. Am I obliged to use `<pluginManagement>` in the parent and add on every module the plugin?

Comment: @gvdm That is a different problem. Best practice would be to define the plugin inside `<pluginManagement>` of the parent, along with some default configuration, and let modules declare it when needed.