# Maven run Jetty Plugin by command line specifying contextPath

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I'm on IntelliJ IDEA CE and I'm running a war application by means of the Maven Jetty Plugin.

I don't have the plugin in my pom.xml (and I don't want to), so I'm running directly the web server with this command:

```
mvn org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.26.v20200117:run-exploded
```

It works fine but it doesn't apply the **contextPath** specified in the xml file *src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml*

I would like to specify the right contextPath from the terminal command.
The [documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin) doesn't say anything specific about this.
The tests I've made (without any successful result) are the following:

```
mvn org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.26.v20200117:run-exploded -Dproject.artifactId='/project'
mvn org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.26.v20200117:run-exploded -DcontextPath='/project'
mvn org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.26.v20200117:run-exploded -Dconfiguration.webApp.contextPath="/project"
mvn org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.26.v20200117:run-exploded -Djetty.configuration.webApp.contextPath="/project"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: According to the documentation, <contextPath> The context path for your webapp. By default, this is set to the /${project.artifactId} from the project's pom.xml.   Therefore I dont understand the need to try and override it?

Comment: The `contextPath` configurable was deprecated in Jetty 7.6.13 and finally removed in Jetty 9.0.0.  The value for `<webApp><contextPath>` in 9.x has always been `/` not the `/${project.artifactId}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ultimately a generic maven tip, not Jetty specific.

In other words, how to figure out what you can do with a maven plugin.

```sh
$ mvn org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.26.v20200117:help
...(snip)...

jetty:help
  Display help information on jetty-maven-plugin.
  Call mvn jetty:help -Ddetail=true -Dgoal=<goal-name> to display parameter
  details.
```

So lets see what the details are on goal `:run-exploded` ...

```sh
$ mvn org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.26.v20200117:help -Ddetail=true -Dgoal=run-exploded
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.26.v20200117:help (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Jetty :: Jetty Maven Plugin 9.4.26.v20200117
  Jetty maven plugins

jetty:run-exploded
  This goal is used to assemble your webapp into an exploded war and
  automatically deploy it to Jetty.
  
  Once invoked, the plugin runs continuously, and can be configured to scan for
  changes in the pom.xml and to WEB-INF/web.xml, WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib
  and hot redeploy when a change is detected.
  
  You may also specify the location of a jetty.xml file whose contents will be
  applied before any plugin configuration. This can be used, for example, to
  deploy a static webapp that is not part of your maven build.

  Available parameters:

    contextHandlers
      List of other contexts to set up. Consider using instead the <jettyXml>
      element to specify external jetty xml config file. Optional.

    contextXml
      Location of a context xml configuration file whose contents will be
      applied to the webapp AFTER anything in <webApp>.Optional.

    dumpOnStart (Default: false)
      Use the dump() facility of jetty to print out the server configuration to
      logging
      User property: dumponStart

    excludedGoals
      List of goals that are NOT to be used

    httpConnector
      A ServerConnector to use.

    jettyXml
      Comma separated list of a jetty xml configuration files whose contents
      will be applied before any plugin configuration. Optional.

    loginServices
      List of security realms to set up. Consider using instead the <jettyXml>
      element to specify external jetty xml config file. Optional.

    nonBlocking (Default: false)
      Determines whether or not the server blocks when started. The default
      behavior (false) will cause the server to pause other processes while it
      continues to handle web requests. This is useful when starting the server
      with the intent to work with it interactively. This is the behaviour of
      the jetty:run, jetty:run-war, jetty:run-war-exploded goals.
      
      If true, the server will not block the execution of subsequent code. This
      is the behaviour of the jetty:start and default behaviour of the
      jetty:deploy goals.

    reload (Default: automatic)
      reload can be set to either 'automatic' or 'manual' if 'manual' then the
      context can be reloaded by a linefeed in the console if 'automatic' then
      traditional reloading on changed files is enabled.
      User property: jetty.reload

    requestLog
      A RequestLog implementation to use for the webapp at runtime. Consider
      using instead the <jettyXml> element to specify external jetty xml config
      file. Optional.

    scanIntervalSeconds (Default: 0)
      The interval in seconds to scan the webapp for changes and restart the
      context if necessary. Ignored if reload is enabled. Disabled by default.
      Required: Yes
      User property: jetty.scanIntervalSeconds

    server
      A wrapper for the Server object

    skip (Default: false)
      Skip this mojo execution.
      User property: jetty.skip

    stopKey
      Key to provide when stopping jetty on executing java -DSTOP.KEY=<stopKey>
      -DSTOP.PORT=<stopPort> -jar start.jar --stop

    stopPort
      Port to listen to stop jetty on executing -DSTOP.PORT=<stopPort>
      -DSTOP.KEY=<stopKey> -jar start.jar --stop

    supportedPackagings
      Per default this goal support only war packaging. If your project use an
      other type please configure it here.

    systemProperties
      System properties to set before execution. Note that these properties will
      NOT override System properties that have been set on the command line or
      by the JVM. They WILL override System properties that have been set via
      systemPropertiesFile. Optional.

    systemPropertiesFile
      File containing system properties to be set before execution Note that
      these properties will NOT override System properties that have been set on
      the command line, by the JVM, or directly in the POM via systemProperties.
      Optional.
      User property: jetty.systemPropertiesFile

    useProvidedScope (Default: false)
      Whether or not to include dependencies on the plugin's classpath with
      <scope>provided</scope> Use WITH CAUTION as you may wind up with duplicate
      jars/classes.

    war (Default: ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName})
      The location of the war file.
      Required: Yes

    webApp
      An instance of org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext that represents the
      webapp. Use any of its setters to configure the webapp. This is the
      preferred and most flexible method of configuration, rather than using the
      (deprecated) individual parameters like 'tmpDirectory', 'contextPath' etc.
```

This tells you that the configuration for the `webApp` is where you set the `contextPath`

Unfortunately, that's a complex object and you cannot specify that on the command line.

So edit your `pom.xml` to include it.

```xml
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <webApp>
              <contextPath>/foo</contextPath>
            </webApp>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
  ...
```

See also [How to define complex Maven properties in the comand line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40023283/how-to-define-complex-maven-properties-in-the-comand-line)

Comment: I thought the initial question had a reluctance to adding the plugin to the pom and indeed, it was mentioned in the above answer.

I am unable to edit this answer so added another version (that also requires adding the plugin) below. The advantage is that the contextPath can be substituted from the command line as the original question needed.

Comment: The complex object in the plugin configuration prevents you success without editing the pom.  The followup link in "See also" is how you could do it without hardcoding a contextPath in the pom, and allowing it to be configured on the command line.  Your followup answer just duplicated another answer.

Comment: Agree with this comment

Answer (score 0):

1. Here is the link
   https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#jetty-maven-plugin
2. Here is the commandline:

```
mvn jetty:run -Dcontext=/abc
```

3. This command line is for the following pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.rahul.soAnswer</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-run</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jetty-answer</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.44.v20210927</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>${context}</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

You can choose to add more detail to the configuration as per your application needs

Comment: I deleted this answer initially, but then eventually added it back because adding the plugin seemed ok. But this answer is really an extension of the first one.